# Magento: Empty Payment Html in Methods.phtml

Tags: magento, email, methods, payment, checkout

I’ve got a problem with the payment methods for my checkout. When I reach the Checkout Step for the Payment Methods, the several options are displayed but I am getting no further Information to the Methods “Bank Payment” and “Cash on Delivery” when I click on the radio button.

It seems to me that **getPaymentMethodFormHtml** (checkout/onepage/payment/methods.phtml) is empty for these Methods. As a result of this issue, I am getting no information in the Order Confirmation Mail (like Bank Name, Cash on Delivery Fee).

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot, also are you using any custom payment method?

Comment: We're using Phoenix_BankPayment, Phoenix_CashOnDelivery, PayPal and Purchase Order for this Store!

http://img507.imageshack.us/img507/382/paymentan.png

Comment: Did you check your server error logs?

Comment: yeah, there's nothing special. FYI: It's working fine for "PayPal" but for the other methods, I don't get any output...

Answer (score 0):

Your error should be in

```
 /app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/payment/form/[cc.phtml]
 /app/design/frontend/default/default/template/payment/form/[cc.phtml]
```

You may need to take a look at each payment method to see the path for their template

e.g

```
<?php
class MagePal_CimPaymentPro_Block_Form_Payment extends Mage_Payment_Block_Form_Cc
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->setTemplate('magepal/cimpaymentpro/payment/form/cc.phtml');    
    }
```

Also, you may want to check to make sure you don't have any javascript error on that page.

You could also use `Inspect Element` in chrome/Firefox (or firebug) to see if the html is hidden by css